# TestRestTemplate - migrating from spring boot 1.5 to 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I migrated my code base from spring boot 1.5 to 2.0 - I've encountered that this constructor in my tests from 1.5 has been completely removed in 2.0.
& they doesnt sem to be an alternative in spring boot 2.0?

TestRestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate(restTemplate.getRestTemplate(),"username","password");

Class:
org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass a now `RestTemplateBuilder` instead of a `RestTemplate`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html

> TestRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder, String username, String password, TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption... httpClientOptions)
>   Create a new TestRestTemplate instance with the specified credentials.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but then my tests keep throwing the exception:                                             Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified

Comment: @Autowired
    protected RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

Comment: It seems to be with the RestTemplateBuilder I somehow have to specify the target host and port where in 1.5 I didnt

Comment: I found away around it for now if I changed to this: @SpringBootTest(classes = AuthApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT) and then in my tests if I add http://localhost:<myport> to the tests all work fine. Only issue is I dont want a fixed port in my tests, in 1.5 I was able to have random_port...